# DNS record: admin.*.domain.com => 1.1.1.1 & *.domain.com => 2.2.2.2

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, record

Is it possible to make such a record that all pages starting with `admin` is redirected to one IP and anything else is redirected to another IP:

```
admin.some.example.com   => 1.1.1.1
admin.thing.example.com  => 1.1.1.1
admin.else.example.com   => 1.1.1.1

some.example.com         => 2.2.2.2
thing.example.com        => 2.2.2.2
else.example.com         => 2.2.2.2
```

Note that `some`, `thing` & `else` can be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do this (using wildcard labels) with a standard DNS server like BIND. You will have to implement a custom DNS server. A custom DNS server can generate whatever answer it wants in response to queries. Note that if you implement a custom DNS server that does this, supporting DNSSEC will be the biggest difficulty.

Comment: Yes. That's a basic wildcard record.